# How to make cython a requirement for a pip install?

Tags: pip, pypi

When creating a Python package and uploading it to `pypi`, it will automatically install the requirements that are put in the `setup.py` file under `install_requires`, e.g.

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
  name = 'a_package',
  packages = ['a_package'],
  install_requires=['another_package']
)
```

When the package has a cython extension (and `.pyx` files instead of `.c`/`.cpp` files), the `setup.py` file will need to import cython to create an installable extension, e.g.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
setup(
  name = 'a_package',
  packages = ['a_package'],
  install_requires=['another_package'],
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = [Extension('the_extension', sources=['a_file.pyx'])]
)
```

But since Cython is imported before executing the `setup` part, when trying to install this package through  `pip` from source (rather than from a wheel) downloaded from `pypi`, it will fail to install due to not being able to import `cython`, as it has not reached the part with the requirements yet.

I’m wondering what can be done to ensure that a `pip` install of this package from `pypi` will install `cython` before it tries to import it. Adding a `requirements.txt` with `cython` does not seem to add automatic-install requirements for files downloaded from `pypi`.

Now, I realize it’s possible to just `pip install cython` before `pip install thispackage`, but I’m wondering if there’s a better fix that would allow to install the package along with cython directly from `pypi` when it’s not possible to run an additional command (without resorting to uploading the `.c.` files and ajusting the `setup.py` file to use them instead of the `.pyx`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're describing is a "build time dependency", and this is precisely the use case "[PEP 518 -- Specifying Minimum Build System Requirements for Python Projects](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/)" was created for.

You can specify `cython` as a build-time dependency by adding a `pyproject.toml` file like:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["cython"]
```

Then when installing your package with a modern version of `pip` (or another PEP 518 compatible installer), `cython` will be installed into the build environment before your `setup.py` script is run.

Comment: I see that file doesn't get included into the package by default with `python setup.py sdist` - does it need to be added to `MANIFEST.in` or does it have some effect on the package file generated by `setuptools` or `distutils`?

Comment: You'll need to use `setuptools` in your `setup.py` file as well. PEP 518 support has not (and likely will not) be added to `distutils`.